# Django Conditional Many-to-One Relationship?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have three models:

- Product
- Variation
- BundledItem

Variation and BundledItem each have a many-to-one relationship with Product.

A Product's 'type' (CharField with choices) can be 'simple', 'variable', or 'bundle'.

I want to ensure that a Variation can only be related to a Product of type 'variable' and a BundledItem can only be related to a Product of type 'bundle'.

How can I implement this as a condition or verify the Product type as part of linking a Variation/BundledItem?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the products in the query to have the desired type:

```
Product.object.filter(type='simple')
```

This will give you all products with type 'simple'

After that you can filter it further, for example by the id or product name:

```
Product.object.filter(name='my_product_name')
```

This type of querying can also be done in one command by combining the filters:

```
Product.object.filter(type='simple', name='my_product_name')
```

Check official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/) on making queries, it is very helpful